# how to base64 encode images in wordpress template

Tags: images, seo

I want to encode images in base64 for better solution to SEO proposes, I am fix some issues in audit and it say to use new image formats then load images as default like `<img src='path/to/image.jpg'/>` so on my research I found that base64 encoded images solve this warning in audit.

Comment: Using a base64 encoded image src might make the warning go away, but you haven't actually solved the problem. It's still a JPG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your file `functions.php` in your template put this funcitons

```
/**
* @param $path
* @return string
* @author https://github.com/ozzpy
*/
function imageEncode($path)
{
$path  = __DIR__."/".$path;
$image = file_get_contents($path);
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$type  = $finfo->buffer($image);
return "data:".$type.";charset=utf-8;base64,".base64_encode($image);
}

/**
 * @param $path
 * @return string
 * @author https://github.com/ozzpy
 */
function imageEncodePath($path)
{
$image = file_get_contents($path);
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$type  = $finfo->buffer($image);
return "data:".$type.";charset=utf-8;base64,".base64_encode($image);
}


/**
 * @param $path
 * @return string
 * @author https://github.com/ozzpy
 */
function imageEncodeURL($path)
{
$image = file_get_contents($path);
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$type  = $finfo->buffer($image);
return "data:".$type.";charset=utf-8;base64,".base64_encode($image);
}
```

in your html files in your template use it like:

template level:
`<img src="<?php echo imageEncode("img/logo.jpeg");?>"/>`

another path level:
`<img src="<?php echo imageEncodePath(__DIR__."/images/slider.png");?>"/>`

outside url level:
`<img src="<?php echo imageEncodeURL("https://somedomain.com/img/image.jpeg");?>"/>`